How to render razor pages dynamically on nav-tabs in _layout when my pages are selected from navigation menu
Hello I’m new in razor & UI & JS technologies. I am trying to make a design which will render my razor pages dynamically on nav-tabs in my _layout when my pages is selected (from top navigation menu). Something similar.
**Step1) ** I created a razor project. I added two razor pages
“MyPage_1.cshtml.cs” (code-C#):
namespace MyRazorDynamicTabs.Pages
{
    public class MyPage_1Model : PageModel
    {
        public int MyPageId { get; set; } 
        public void OnGet()
        {
            MyPageId = 1;
        }
    }
}

“MyPage_2.cshtml.cs” (code-C#):
namespace MyRazorDynamicTabs.Pages
{
    public class MyPage_2Model : PageModel
    {
        public int MyPageId { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            MyPageId = 2;
        }
    }
}

And then I added some contents in pages showing their own page Id:
“MyPage_1.cshtml” (razor page):

@page
@model MyRazorDynamicTabs.Pages.MyPage_1Model
@{}
<b>This tab content From MyPage_1, the page id is: + @Model.MyPageId</b>

“MyPage_2.cshtml” (razor page):

@page
@model MyRazorDynamicTabs.Pages.MyPage_2Model
@{}
<b>This tab content From MyPage_2, the page id is: + @Model.MyPageId</b>

Step 2) I added two new nav-items on the navbar at _Layout.cshtml  for my pages:

<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
...
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_1">MyPage1</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_2">MyPage2</a></li>
</ul>

This works as usual without dynamic tabbing. @RenderBody() render my pages one by one in class=”container” as expected:
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

Step 3) Now I want to change the container design and add nav-tab, tab-content and tab-panel elements as follow, where my dynamic tabs are expected to be populated;
  <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @*@RenderBody()*@

            <!-- nav tabs -->
            <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#idHome" role"="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- tab-content > tab panes -->
            <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="idHome">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>
    </div>

Home tab in tab-panel will be generated by default when layout is loaded. This also works:
Step 4) I add some javascript in my layout in order to open new tab when my pages are selected from the top navigation menu. Ref: How to add another tab dynamically to bootstrap tabs).
I add following bootstrap to <head> section in my layout:
<head>
....
....
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

And the following Javascript in my layout. This is for check & add new tab if one of My Pages is clicked. And remove tabs;
<script>
        function AddTab(tabId, tablabel, aspPage) {

        /* A> CHECK the Tab already exit.*/
        if (IsTabExist(tabId)) {
            /* B > IF YES, show the existing Tab and return */
            return showTab(tabId);
        }

        /* IF NO,means tab does not exit, so let's create it.*/
        var navTabs = $('#tab-list');
        var tabContents = $('#tab-content');

        /* C.1> Create a new tab <li><a> under “tab-list”, */
        var new_li = $('<li>').append($('<a>')
            .attr('id', '#' + tabId)
            .attr('href', '#' + tabId)
            .attr('role', 'tab')
            .attr('data-toggle', 'tab')
            //.attr('data-target', tabId)
            .append(tablabel + '<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this tab">×</button>'));

        /* C.2> Create a new <div> with “tab-pane” class under “tab-content” */
        var new_tab = $('<div>')
            .addClass('tab-pane fade active')
            .attr('id', tabId)
            /* C.3> Append some “static content” into <div> “tab-pane” */
            .append(function () {
                return "<b>This tab content is expected coming from page: " + aspPage + ".</b>";
            });

        navTabs.append(new_li);
        tabContents.append(new_tab);

        /* B > show the created Tab */
        showTab(tabId);
    }

    /* A> CHECK the Tab already exit.*/
    function IsTabExist(tabId) {
        var selectedTabId = '#' + tabId;
        for (const elements of document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs li a')) {
            var currTabId = elements.getAttribute('id');
            if (currTabId == selectedTabId) {
                return true
            }
        };
        return false;
    }


    /* B> Get id from element nav-tabs li a and click() it*/
    function showTab(navTab_Li_a_Id) {
        //$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + navTab_Li_a_Id + '"]').tab('show');
        let resultsTab = document.getElementById('#' + navTab_Li_a_Id);
        resultsTab.click();
    };

    /* D> Close (remove) the tab when needed with Button Click. And go to the last tab */
    $('#tab-list').on('click', '.close', function () {
        var tabId = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
        $(this).parents('li').remove();
        $(tabId).remove();

        //display last tab after remove tabId
        //var tabFirst = $('#tab-list a:last');
        //tabFirst.tab('show');

        var currentTabList = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs li a');
        var lastTab = currentTabList[currentTabList.length - 1];
        lastTab.click();

    });

</script>

A “static content” is appended manually to the “tab-pane” as shown code block above at C.3. This just for testing js functions (not for rendering my razor pages which is the main issue...).
Step 5) I change My Pages nav-link attributes by adding onclick=AddTab(..) and parameters to js : tab Id, tab label and page url (Page Url is used just for tab content, not for routing or page rendering for now):
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
....
         @*<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_1">MyPage1</a>*@
         <a class="nav-link text-dark" onclick="AddTab('idMyPage1','MyPage 1','/MyPage_1')">MyPage 1</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">

         @*<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_2">MyPage2</a>*@
         <a class="nav-link text-dark" onclick="AddTab('idMyPage2','MyPage 2','/MyPage_2')">MyPage 2</a>

     </li>
 </ul>

asp-page routings on My Pages are closed for now. It’s seems works:
Step5 Output Image
Step 6) The main question is not answered yet. How can I render my razor pages “MyPage_1.cshtml” and “MyPage_2.cshtml” dynamically into tabs in my layout similar to design as explained above?
I try to add again asp-page attribute in My Pages on navbar in layout:
<li class="nav-item">
    @*<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_1">MyPage1</a>*@
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" onclick="AddTab('idMyPage1','MyPage 1','/MyPage_1')"  asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_1">MyPage 1</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">

    @*<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_2">MyPage2</a>*@
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" onclick="AddTab('idMyPage2','MyPage 2','/MyPage_2')"  asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_2">MyPage 2</a>

</li>

When I click “My Page 1” on navbar, this page is rendered under Home tab. As the pages are rendered under Home tab (No modifiacation on Step 3). It seems normal but not the situation that I am aiming:
Step6 Output Image
I read some articles and blogs about dynamic tabbing, I tried to modify them for my razor project. I modified my C.3 code block above (Step 4 AddTab) by trying append my pages as tab content using Ajax, window.location.href, or rendering my pages as partial.   But I couldn’t figure out how to generate my razor pages under tabs dynamically. I will really appreciate any feedback / explanation / examples regarding this issue. Thank you in advance.

I found some solution using Ajax and DOMParser() as explained below;

Add a common html element tag which will be used to encounter my pages which will be rendered in tav-tabs, for example,

I added the 'section' element to my page1:


    <section> <b>This tab content From MyPage_1, the page id is: + @Model.MyPageId</b></section>




I changed my js code part C.3 as follow (see function AddTab above)

/* C.3> Append my Page into  “tab-pane” */
.append(function () {
 

    $.ajax({
        url: aspPage,
        datatype: "html",
        type: "get",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            
/* Initialize the DOM parser */
            const parser = new DOMParser()

            /* Parse the text/html to doc*/
            const doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html")
            var myPageSection = doc.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].innerHTML

            /* Set it to MyPage tab-pane in Layout and return*/
            return (document.getElementById(tabId).innerHTML = myPageSection);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

});


I change the My Page 1 nav-link in order to trigger AddTab js as follow:



<li class="nav-item">
@*<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MyPage_1">MyPage1</a>*@
<a class="nav-link text-dark" onclick="AddTab('idMyPage1','MyPage 1','/MyPage_1')">MyPage 1</a>
</li>




Finaly, when I click My Page 1 on top navigation;


AddTab javascript will generate a new tab with id= 'idMyPage1' and Tab Label='MyPage 1'
Ajax will load url = '/MyPage_1'
FIRST 'section' part on returning html document will be retrieven by DOMParser and doc.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].innerHTML (Assuming that there is no a 'section' part in the main layout page)
And 'section' part in razor My Page will be added to tab-pane.

ATTENTION: DOMParser parseFromString retrieve only style and html part, but no inline javascripts ('script' part in My Page 1). If you want render your razor pages dynamically in new nav-tabs with this method:
a) you have to move your inline javascript to external js and refer them at Layout 'head', For example:


<head>
. . . 
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/my/MyPage_1.js"></script>
. . .
</head>



b) You have to use html tag id unique for ALL my razor Pages, otherwise if two razor pages are rendered in two different nav-tabs, same html element id(s) will be conflicted.
As I said, I am not expert on .net core UI technologies & js. This solution worked for me, I will always appreciate any enhancement, +/- opinions about this method.
